# Creating a jpeg file with metadata

Tags: java, image, metadata, javax.imageio

I have a **Java** application that creates a **BufferedImage** and saves it to disk as a JPEG.  I'd really like to add a caption to the image.  To prevent the image from getting crowded out by text on the image itself, it'd be great if I could write the caption to the JPEG's metadata.

I've been searching all over the place for a solution, but haven't found anything satisfactory.  Sanselan comes up a lot, but I haven't figured out how to use it properly.  I found examples that modify existing metadata, but my files don't contain metadata as they are simply created from ImageIO.write() or Sanselan.writeImage().

I found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755185/how-to-add-comments-to-a-jpeg-file-using-c) that does what I'm looking for, but it's in C# and I need Java.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the package you want to look at is javax.imageio.metadata

The IIOMetaData class (which has a concrete subclass for JPEG) contains methods to get metadata information in various formats, including as an XML DOM tree root node.

Comment: oh, and you can write a tree back with setFromTree(), which is in retrospect what you were really asking :)P