# How do you get the dateTaken using imageIO (JPEG)?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Does anyone know how to extract the date a jpeg image was taken/create from the jpeg meta data using imageio?

Comment: Have you looked into using the javax.imageio.metadata package?  Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909317/creating-a-jpeg-file-with-metadata

Answer (score 1):

This package should help you extract the metadata you need.
http://www.drewnoakes.com/drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [Java Advanced Imaging API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-1-0-2-140451.html).

[Java doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/index.html)
[PDF with examples here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151220104019/http://babypod.googlecode.com/files/rita_v11_n1_p93a124.pdf)