# image captions inside JPG files?

Tags: image, jpeg, caption

Is there a standard to put image captions INTO/INSIDE a .jpg/jpeg files (i.e. similar to MP3-tags that travel within the file and are displayed by most players)? Is there a tool for this (preferably for Windoze in my case)?

Does the JPEG standard not provide that feature? I always thought, it does, but searching for a while I couldn't find anything with regard to image captions.

Answer (score 1):

The common standard for annotating JPEG images (TIFF is also supported) are the [IPTC data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTC_Information_Interchange_Model). Similar to ID3 the data is appended to the JPEG image.

In difference to Exif data which was designed to save data about the camera and it's settings when the picture was taken, IPTC data allows you to set keywords, captions, copyright string and much more.

A lot of picture managing software do support reading and writing IPTC data.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is probably meta-data not caption. Google that. Failing that, just batch it with a c# script.

[How to Add 'Comments' to a JPEG File Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755185/how-to-add-comments-to-a-jpeg-file-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint! JPEG **Exif** metadata was the missing keyword or search term. Exif seems to allow setting all kind of tags and there are misc. tools allowing to read and edit these. Still haven't decided on which one, yet, but your advice got me going.
Thanks!
M.

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile I found out that Exif, IPTC and XMP are all standards that support the annotation of JPG pictures. Apparently one of the problems is, that there are too many standards and each program is supporting a different one (or subset). But the real disappointment for me is, that my little server (Synology) that has a very nice built-in photo album function which is very well suited to provide friends and family access to your photos, doesn't support any of these.... :-(