# Changing "DateTaken" of a photo

Tags: c#, bitmap, exif

I just came back from a trip to the US, and after editing all the photos, I noticed that the camera used the Israeli time zone, and not the american. There is a 7 hours time difference, so it's a big problem for me. I have 175GB of photos, but I care "only" about 350 photos. I can't edit their EXIF manually, so I thought about using C#.

The idea is that it will read each photo's EXIF, get the time, and set the time minus 7 hours in the original photo. I tried using the Image class, but it doesn't work. I tried using the bitmapMetadate, and it worked! I've managed to get the time and do minus seven hours, but I have no idea how to save it. How can I do it? Thanks!

```
    public static string PhotoToBeEdited(FileInfo f)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(f.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        BitmapSource img = BitmapFrame.Create(fs);
        BitmapMetadata md = (BitmapMetadata)img.Metadata;
        string date = md.DateTaken;
        Console.WriteLine(date);
        DateTime dt= DateTime.Parse(date);
        date = dt.AddHours(-7).ToString();

        [...]

        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way I've found is using technic described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15621/EXIF-tag-Editor-for-JPG-images) and System.Drawing.Bitmap;

The code should be like this:

```
  public void ChangeDateTaken(string path)
    {
        Image theImage = new Bitmap(path);
        PropertyItem[] propItems = theImage.PropertyItems;
        Encoding _Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var DataTakenProperty1 = propItems.Where(a => a.Id.ToString("x") == "9004").FirstOrDefault();
        var DataTakenProperty2 = propItems.Where(a => a.Id.ToString("x") == "9003").FirstOrDefault();
        string originalDateString = _Encoding.GetString(DataTakenProperty1.Value);
        originalDateString = originalDateString.Remove(originalDateString.Length - 1);
        DateTime originalDate = DateTime.ParseExact(originalDateString, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", null);

        originalDate = originalDate.AddHours(-7);


        DataTakenProperty1.Value = _Encoding.GetBytes(originalDate.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss") + '\0');
        DataTakenProperty2.Value = _Encoding.GetBytes(originalDate.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss") + '\0');
        theImage.SetPropertyItem(DataTakenProperty1);
        theImage.SetPropertyItem(DataTakenProperty2);
        string new_path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\_" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        theImage.Save(new_path);
        theImage.Dispose();
    }
```

Don't forget to add System.Drawing assembly.
Also you will probably need to adjust DateTime format to your culture, if needed

Comment: Thanks! You are a genius!

Comment: **Hint:** If the date taken isn't specified yet, you have to create new propItems. This is not so easy, because the constructor doesn't allow it, but I found a way how to do it **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25162782/1016343).** So you can check DataTakenProperty1 against null, and if it is null, create new propItems.

Answer (score 9):

For .NET Core I use NuGet package ExifLibNet (https://github.com/oozcitak/exiflibrary)

PM> Install-Package ExifLibNet

```
// using ExifLibrary;

var file = ImageFile.FromFile(filename);
file.Properties.Set(ExifTag.DateTimeDigitized, dateTime);
file.Properties.Set(ExifTag.DateTimeOriginal, dateTime);
file.Save(filename);
```

Comment: A LinqPad Script, if you don't like to type to much: https://gist.github.com/heebinho/8df3ef62ac0a480c6f81d50b67f8f00a#file-updatephotocreationdate-linq

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a programming solution, but you can use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#running). I use it for this exact purpose.

> **Date/Time Shift Feature**
>
> Have you ever forgotten to set the date/time on your digital camera
>   before taking a bunch of pictures? ExifTool has a time shift feature
>   that makes it easy to apply a batch fix to the timestamps of the
>   images (eg. change the "Date Picture Taken" reported by Windows
>   Explorer). Say for example that your camera clock was reset to
>   2000:01:01 00:00:00 when you put in a new battery at 2005:11:03
>   10:48:00. Then all of the pictures you took subsequently have
>   timestamps that are wrong by 5 years, 10 months, 2 days, 10 hours and
>   48 minutes. To fix this, put all of the images in the same directory
>   ("DIR") and run exiftool:
>
> ```
> > exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal+=5:10:2 10:48:0" DIR
> ```

You can also set the [TimeZoneOffset](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62082/is-there-any-hope-for-exif-timezoneoffset-as-a-standard) field, in case there's ever software that actually uses it.

Comment: I tried it and i gave up. I have no idea how to use it. Thanks anyway. BTW, you have a great name!