# Change Exif in photo (metadata-extractor) c#

Tags: c#, exif, metadata-extractor

is it possible to change exif data from photos ? I get the exif data thus :

```
var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(file);

foreach (var directory in directories)
{
    foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)
        Console.WriteLine($"[{directory.Name}] {tag.Name} = {tag.Description}");

    if (directory.HasError)
    {
        foreach (var error in directory.Errors)
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {error}");
    }
}
```

Now I need to replace the exif data from other photos to these, is that possible ?

[How to edit EXIF data in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226973/how-to-edit-exif-data-in-net) - its not correct answer, because all this librarycant edit exif , just read

Comment: [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32066893/1132334) for one property. other writable properties should work the same way.

Comment: @dlatikay I found this solution, but i have error `System.NullReferenceException` in line `string originalDateString = _Encoding.GetString(DataTakenProperty1.Value);`

Comment: @Jasen yes, i can read but how i can change exif ? gps, date, camera model and etc

Comment: The metadata you are asking about depends on the image type. Then jpg images in particular have different exif formats which may not all be encoded into the file. You might have some success with [`InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.inplacebitmapmetadatawriter(v=vs.110).aspx). But this stuff can get complicated which is why there are so many 3rd party libraries to hide all the details. The one you are using doesn't appear to handle writing.

Comment: @Jasen images is jpg. The photo is not passed through a third-party program, right from the camera. hidden values should not be

Comment: If you want to do it yourself you'd start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The metadata-extractor library doesn't support writing data back to files.

So the answer to your question is, unfortunately, no.

You will have to find a different method to modify data in your files.

Comment: okey, how i can change without library ?