# C# Set / create DateTaken parameter

Tags: c#, bitmap, exif

I'm tying to set the DateTaken parameter with C#, because I've got a lot of photos without this date.
I only found this comment [changing-datetaken-of-a-photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066893/changing-datetaken-of-a-photo)
In this toppic they are changing it and not creating it.

If use this function, but DataTakenProperty1 or DataTakenProperty2 is null and can not be set.

```
    private static void SetDateTaken(string path, DateTime NEWdate)
    {
        Image theImage = new Bitmap(path);
        PropertyItem[] propItems = theImage.PropertyItems;
        Encoding _Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        var DataTakenPropert = propItems.SetValue(NEWdate.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"), ??How do i know the index??);

        theImage.SetPropertyItem(DataTakenProperty);
        string new_path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\_" + Path.GetFileName(path);
        theImage.Save(new_path);
        theImage.Dispose();
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive this using a little trick, since you can't initiate [PropertyItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.setpropertyitem?view=netframework-4.8) when its null.

> It is difficult to set property items, because the PropertyItem class
>   has no public constructors. One way to work around this restriction is
>   to obtain a PropertyItem by retrieving the PropertyItems property
>   value or calling the GetPropertyItem method of an Image that already
>   has property items. Then you can set the fields of the PropertyItem
>   and pass it to SetPropertyItem.

```
private static void SetDateTaken(string path, string samplePath, DateTime NEWdate)
{         
    Encoding _Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Image theImage = new Bitmap(path);
    PropertyItem[] propItems = theImage.PropertyItems;

    var DataTakenProperty1 = propItems.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.ToString("x") == "9003");
    var DataTakenProperty2 = propItems.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.ToString("x") == "9004");

    //// this is where you do the hack
    if (DataTakenProperty1 == null)
    {
        Image sampleImage = new Bitmap(samplePath);
        PropertyItem fakePropertyItem1 = sampleImage.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.ToString("x") == "9003");
        fakePropertyItem1.Value = _Encoding.GetBytes(NEWdate.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss") + '\0');
        fakePropertyItem1.Len = fakePropertyItem1.Value.Length;
        theImage.SetPropertyItem(fakePropertyItem1);

        PropertyItem fakePropertyItem2 = sampleImage.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.ToString("x") == "9004");
        fakePropertyItem2.Value = _Encoding.GetBytes(NEWdate.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss") + '\0');
        fakePropertyItem2.Len = fakePropertyItem2.Value.Length;
        theImage.SetPropertyItem(fakePropertyItem2);
    }
    else
    {
        DataTakenProperty1.Value = _Encoding.GetBytes(NEWdate.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss") + '\0');
        DataTakenProperty2.Value = _Encoding.GetBytes(NEWdate.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss") + '\0');
        theImage.SetPropertyItem(DataTakenProperty1);
        theImage.SetPropertyItem(DataTakenProperty2);
    }

    theImage.Save(newPath);
    theImage.Dispose();
}
```

[List of PropertyIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Imaging_PropertyItem_Id)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, i'm not getting any error, but unfortantly it's not working. I tried this ID's (also with and without prevois 0x ): 132, 9003, 9004. The DateTaken attribute is still emtpy / explorer isn't showing it

Comment: Did you read answer correctly? Above code is tested and it works also

Comment: hmm, it's not working,
I've added "theImage.Save(path); theImage.Dispose();" and nothing happend.
Ff I read the dei again and then let me show the ID's, the 9004 is not displayed, only [770, 34675, 20752, 20753, 20754]

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem with png types, but for jpg above modified code is working. SamplePath is jpg with DateTaken property.

Comment: yes, png is the problem. with jpg it's working fine. Thank you.
i've got only a few png pictures