# WPF Image is rotated automatically

Tags: wpf

I founnd some strange behaviour with image control in wpf
I have issue with image control. Image is rotated automatically.
I want it to be shown as original.

```
<ImageEdit x:Name="root" Source="/Images/DSC_0100_VerticalOrigation.JPG" />
```

[Devexpress ticket link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T858598/imagegallery-image-rotated-automatically)

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42971094/1506454

Answer (score -1):

This code is working for this

```
void Rotate(Bitmap bmp)
{    
    if (pi == null) return; 

    byte o = pi.Value[0];

    if (o==2) bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
    if (o==3) bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipXY);
    if (o==4) bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
    if (o==5) bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
    if (o==6) bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    if (o==7) bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipY);
    if (o==8) bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `pi` from? Your answer is not helpful, please correct it.