# C# the original point of Bitmap Rotate and Filp

Tags: c#, bitmap

Can someone describe the rotation and filp of image by the RotateFilp() method of the Bitmap to rotate and filp the image? I want to know the followings:

1. The point of rotation and filp by default?
2. The concept of filp and rotation?
3. Explian one of the RotateFlipType enum?

Thanks for any help
Aaron

Comment: Which bit of the documentation do you not understand? You can only rotate 90/180/270 which sounds pretty self explanatory to me.

Comment: @Neil thanks for your commit.  I mainly know which point is  the original of rotation and filp.

Comment: Pick up a physical item and rotate or flip it @AaronWang. You don't need to know "the point".

Comment: The center is the center. For other rotation points you will need to use graphics functions.. - For the fliptype see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971094/getting-correct-image-rotation/42972969#42972969)