# VB.Net Is there away of reading and updating a picture's tags and comments?

Tags: vb.net, image, video, metadata

In File Explorer in Windows 10, going via a file's **Properties | Details** you can set **Tags** and **Comments**.

I want to use these fields for annotating photos and movies created by our wildlife camera, tagging files with "Fox", "Badger" etc. You can add the two fields as columns in **File Explorer** lists.

However it would be very tiresome updating the properties for all 2700 files we have so far, so I have written a program which makes the process much quicker, BUT at the moment the tags and comments for each file go into a text file, which is stored in the same folder as the media file and under a similar name.

Very nice, but it would be much better if the tags and comments could be stored in the media file - the only trouble being that a prolonged search of the web has revealed nothing, or rather a great deal of stuff which appears relevant, but isn't!

So please can someone help me?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820525/how-to-get-and-set-propertyitems-for-an-image

Comment: and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649/how-to-get-the-exif-data-from-a-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: @dbasnett  All those methods imply that you're modifying the original Image object, which can cause *catastrophic* changes in the internal Bitmap (alternation in state). The OP should work at the Shell level (the Bitmap remains untouched) or with Alternate Streams. Of course, none of these settings would persist when the Image is moved elsewhere. Setting (or adding) PropertyItems is instead of course *portable*. But one needs to be very careful and handle the Bitmap data to prevent loss of information. Not easy to accomplish, some compromises required

Comment: Thank you. You gave a few very useful clues, and as a result i have sussed out the Property Ids for a JPG's Tags (40094) and Comments (40092). I am hoping these Ids will be the same for other media files, but I am having difficulties with movies - for which i will raise another post.