# VB.NET writing comments to jpeg file programmatically

Tags: vb.net, metadata, jpeg

I searched stackoverflow and I realized that GetPropertyItem and SetPropertyItem can edit comments in JPEG file

```
Dim images As Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\Sample.jpeg")
Dim MSGF As New ArrayList
Dim ID() As String = {"hello ","i am here"}
Dim propItem As PropertyItem = images.GetPropertyItem(40092)
Dim encoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)
encoderParameters.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L)

For i = 0 To ID.Length - 1
    Dim TEMP As String = ID(i)
    For II = 0 To TEMP.Length - 1
        MSGF.Add(Convert.ToInt32(TEMP(II)))
    Next
Next
For i = 0 To MSGF.Count - 1
    propItem.Value.SetValue(Convert.ToByte(MSGF(i)), i)
Next

images.SetPropertyItem(propItem)
images.Save(TextBox1.Text & "\" & "1" & TextBox2.Text)
```

What I realized was I can get comments from jpeg file by GetPropertyItem. However, comments is based on the ascii code. Therefore, I was trying to convert comment that I wanted to insert to ascii code.

```
propItem.Value.SetValue(Convert.ToByte(MSGF(i)), i)
```

This part was actually changed comments which already existed in the jpeg file.
However, if there is no comments in jpeg file, `propItem.value.setValue` doesn't work because there is nothing to edit.

Is there anyway to just add comments to jpeg file?

Comment: Based on [the MSDN page for PropertyItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem(v=vs.110).aspx), `A PropertyItem object is used to retrieve and to change the metadata of existing image files, not to create the metadata.`, so I don't think the approach is correct. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23762564/832052) for an entirely different approach, which seems to do what you need.

Comment: @djv thanks for your answer. i think, i saw this solution before. And, I was trying to convert c# version to VB.NET. But, it wasn't working very well. I wish i can find VB.NET way to add comments to jpeg file :(

Comment: Did you try using an [**online converter**](http://converter.telerik.com)?

Comment: Converted the code for you in an answer

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23762564/832052), it could be as simple as this:

```vb
Dim jpeg = New JpegMetadataAdapter(pathToJpeg)
jpeg.Metadata.Comment = "Some comments"
jpeg.Metadata.Title = "A title"
jpeg.Save()
' Saves the jpeg in-place
jpeg.SaveAs(someNewPath)
' Saves with a new path
```

Here is the class:

```
Public Class JpegMetadataAdapter
    Private ReadOnly path As String
    Private frame As BitmapFrame
    Public ReadOnly Metadata As BitmapMetadata

    Public Sub New(path As String)
        Me.path = path
        frame = getBitmapFrame(path)
        Metadata = DirectCast(frame.Metadata.Clone(), BitmapMetadata)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Save()
        SaveAs(path)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveAs(path As String)
        Dim encoder As New JpegBitmapEncoder()
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(frame, frame.Thumbnail, Metadata, frame.ColorContexts))
        Using stream As Stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            encoder.Save(stream)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function getBitmapFrame(path As String) As BitmapFrame
        Dim decoder As BitmapDecoder = Nothing
        Using stream As Stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
            decoder = New JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad)
        End Using
        Return decoder.Frames(0)
    End Function
End Class
```