# Storing Filename,Location and Size in an Array to Remember Selection Rectangle in Images

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, list

I have 2 panels. The first panel shows a list of image files. When a user selects a file its displayed in a picturebox in the right panel. The user is allowed to select an area in the image. I need to save this selection for future use ie. to show the selection when this image is selected again.
I intend to use an array with Multiple Data types

```
[Filename(string),Location(Point),Size(Size)]
```

Is this approach okay? Is there a better approach to solve this issue?

Comment: See this simple example: [How to call a method that uses coordinates variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53708936/7444103). More or less what the answers here are suggesting. You need a specialized class that can hold all the informations needed to store, serialize and restore the selections key values. The notes there may be interesting.

Comment: Also, you can use Jpeg metadata in order to save your parameter permanently. [Here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23762564/4527628)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the proper thing to do here is to first define a class to store the state associated to a single picturebox:

```
class PictureboxState
{
  public string Filename { get; set }
  public Point Location { get; set; }
  public Size Size { get; set; }
}
```

Then you keep an array of instances of this class; or even better, a dictionary where the keys are the pictureboxes (or something else that can identify the picturebox) and the values are the state objects.

Comment: The keys can be fullfilepath as it is unique for each selection.